# How to host wordpress website on a separate server (Path in subdirectory)

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wordpress

I have an e-commerce website and a blog, both under same domain. Let's assume

- www.xyz.com (Ecommerce Website - Built in Java - Used tomcat as Servlet Container)
- www.xyz.com/blog (Wordpress blog)

I am using Nginx as a proxy web server. For all requests starting with **/blog** are passed to wordpress directly, rest other requests are handled by tomcat. My webserver is AWS EC2 running Ubuntu as OS.

I am looking to remove wordpress website from this server and host it somewhere else, maybe a separate EC2 or a lightsail server. But I want to keep the same subdirectory structure for blog. Any inputs, how can I make it possible?

Comment: If you are already proxying the requests to WordPress you only need to change the target in the proxy configuration.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Is it possible to target to a different server altogether without changing url through nginx?

Comment: You can proxy to anything you like, anywhere, using Nginx.